# $Int f^{-1}(Int B) = f^{-1}(Int B)$ where int means interior set.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I cannot understand why this equality holds:

$Int f^{-1}(Int B) = f^{-1}(Int B)$

int means interior set of the set B. And I know, that interior is the largest open subset in set(B)

$f$ is continious function

Comment: Can you provide more details? What is $f$?

Comment: @bradipolpo f is continious function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is continuous then $f^{-1}(\mathsf{Int}(B))$ as preimage of an open set is open.

Then consequently it coincides with its interior.

This because $f^{-1}(\mathsf{Int}(B))$ is evidently the largest open set that is contained in $f^{-1}(\mathsf{Int}(B))$.